# Solve matrix equation for matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

Is there any function like Solve but designed to deal with matrix equations?
Something like:

```
mA = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
mC = {{19, 22}, {43, 50}};
Solve[mA.mX == mC, mX]  (* should return {{5, 6}, {7, 8}} *)
```

I know that you could just type

```
Inverse[mA].mC
```

but I'm curious if there is other way to do this.

Comment: Get into the habit of using `LinearSolve[]` instead of `Inverse[]`, whenever possible.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mA = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
mC = {{19, 22}, {43, 50}};
mX = Array[X, {2, 2}]
Solve[mA.mX == mC, Flatten[mX]]
```

Will do what you want

Comment: this code now generates an error Flatten
:Nonatomicexpressionexpectedatposition1inFlatten[mX].

Comment: It works in V13.0.  @Manuel Hernandez